# Simple question about try/catch statement

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, nullpointerexception

If I add this try/catch statement in my code:

```
try {
   ...
   method1();

} catch (Exception e) {
   call_method();

}
```

am I invoking "`call_method()`" for any type of exception, at any level such as `java.lang.NullPointerException` inside `method1()` .. right ?

thanks

Comment: One thing to watch out for though... if an exception is thrown in method1 and handled either in that method or somewhere before the exception is thrown to your initial call it won't reach call_method(). Happened to a buddy of mine so I thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am I invoking "call_method()" for any
>   type of exception, at any level such
>   as java.lang.NullPointerException
>   inside method1() .. right ?

Yes........

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will catch anything that extends `Exception`.  Note especially that this include `RuntimeException` and its many subclasses (such as `NullPointerException` as you mention).

It will not catch other `Throwable` objects, i.e. `Error` and its many subclasses.

You should be careful not to write overly-broad exception handlers that will end up concealing important problems.  (Whether that's the case in this example, I can't say.)

Answer (score 0):

That would be a steady: Yes! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. However, the catch block will not trigger for Errors, such as an `OutOfMemoryError`. Which is generally what you want since Errors are supposed to signal fundamental problems an app cannot recover from.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are catching the generic Exception, you will be calling `call_method()` every time an exception is thrown.

You can see here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

That exception is the top level class for the exceptions, in which everything eventually inherits from.

However as a rule of thumb, you generally do not want to catch Exception, rather you want to catch specific errors that are pertaining to your try, catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - for anything that inherits from Exception. Although in general, unless that method is doing something to handle that exception, it's not typically considered "good form" (but I don't try to assume a person's intent).

You may want to look at Throwable as well: here is a good discussion to view:
[When should Throwable be used instead of new Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498217/when-should-throwable-be-used-instead-of-new-exception)

Answer (score 0):

For any exception thrown inside the try block, you will be calling the `call_method()`.

It is because you are trying to catch generic `Exception` object and not some specific object such as `NullPointerException`.

If you try something like this,

```
try { 
  // ....
  method1();
 }
catch(NullPointerException e) {
  // ....
  call_method();
 }
```

then only when you have a `NullPointerException` inside the try block, your catch will catch it & your `call_method()` will be executed.