# Mock unable to generate text file for test cases

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am creating mock to check logger functionality. For that i have interface and create mock for that. But its not working. Any help appreciated.

This is my interface

```
public interface ILoggerMock {

    public void write(String text) throws Throwable;
}
```

And this is my Test class

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

public class LoggerMock {

    @Test
    public void out() throws Throwable {

        ILoggerMock iLoggerMock = Mockito.mock(ILoggerMock.class);

        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable, IOException {
                try {
                    System.out.println("CalculatorMock.out().new Answer() {...}.answer()");

                    Files.write(Paths.get("D:/log/logger.txt"), "Hello!".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // exception handling
                }
                return null;
            }
        }).when(iLoggerMock).write("write");

        List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:/log/logger.txt"));

        for (String line : list) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        //System.out.print("hello");
        assertEquals("Hello!", list.get(0));
    }

}
```

Problem is in mock i am not able to create file. Please help me for creating file.

Comment: Your code which will write the file is wrapped in an `Answer`.  That will only occur when something _calls_ `write` on the mock `ILoggerMock` class somewhere.  Do you pass this instance anywhere which is going to use it?

Comment: yes i am pasing mock into when?

Comment: i am debugging the code but doAnswer() is not called or not even print message on console.

Comment: That would be my point.  You have set up code to be an _answer_ when that object is called.  But nothing is calling it.  You don't have a test case which calls that code.  You don't pass it into other objects which will indirectly call it when invoked, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please see [Is “throws Throwable” good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12564428/1744774) regarding your Interface declaration.

As [@BeUndead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478398) mentions in the comments to the question all Mockito methods in conjunction with `when(...)` just prepare a mock what to do when one of its methods is invoked later.

`Mockito.doAnswer(...).when(iLoggerMock).write("write");` in your code defines what's done once the mock's `write()` method is invoked with the argument `"write"`. So, to actually make the things happen therein you have to invoke `iLoggerMock.write("write")` somewhere after. (But `write` isn't the text you want to write anyway, it's `Hello!`.)

A working code could look like:

### Main class

```java
public interface ILogger {

    public void write( String text ) throws Exception;

    public Path getLog();
}
```

### Test classes

```java
abstract class AbstractLoggerTest {

    protected Path log;

    protected void testWrite( ILogger logger, String text ) throws Exception {

        log = logger.getLog(); // here happens what has been prepared in when(...).thenReturn(...); below

        logger.write( text ); // here happens what has been prepared in doAnswer(...).when(...).write(...); below

        assertEquals( "Wrong line count", 1,
                Files.lines( log )
                        .map( line -> {
                            //System.out.println( line );  // Uncomment this if you really must.
                            // Actually we are using automated tests for this:
                            // To prevent having to trace program or test outputs manually.
                            assertEquals( "Written and read text not equal", text, line );
                            return line;
                        } ).count() );
    }

    protected String textToWrite( ILogger forLogger, Path toLog ) {

        return String.format( "Text from %s written to %s.",
                forLogger.getClass().getName(), toLog );
    }
}
```

```java
public class ILoggerTest extends AbstractLoggerTest {

    private static final String LOG_FILE = "target/interface.log.txt";

    @Mock
    private ILogger logger;

    @Before
    public void before() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
        log = Paths.get( LOG_FILE );
        when( logger.getLog() ).thenReturn( LOG ); // this prepares the mock what to do when `logger.getLog()` is invoked later
    }

    @Test
    public void testWrite() throws Exception {

        final String TEXT_TO_WRITE = textToWrite( logger, log );

        doAnswer( new Answer<Void>() {

            @Override
            public Void answer( InvocationOnMock invocation ) throws IOException {

                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                Files.writeString( log, (String) args[0] );
                return null;
            }
        } ).when( logger ).write( any() ); // this prepares the mock what to do when `logger.write()` is invoked
                                           // with any argument later (String, in this case. The argument type 
                                           // will get inferred by the compiler.) 


        testWrite( logger, TEXT_TO_WRITE );
        verify( logger ).write( TEXT_TO_WRITE );
    }
}
```

The class `AbstractLoggerTest` has the advantage that if an `ILogger` implementation is created in the future [constructors and setters/getters omitted for brevity]:

### Main classes

```java
public abstract class AbstractLogger implements ILogger {

    protected Path log;

    @Override
    public void write( String text ) throws IOException {

        Files.writeString( log, text );
    }

    @Override
    public Path getLog() {

        return log;
    }
}
```

```java
public class TextLogger extends AbstractLogger {

    {
        log = Paths.get( "target/log.txt" );
    }
}
```

its **test class** would simply look like:

```java
public class TextLoggerTest extends AbstractLoggerTest {

    @Test
    public void testWrite() throws Exception {

        ILogger logger = new TextLogger();
        testWrite( logger, textToWrite( logger, logger.getLog() ) );
    }
}
```